Allow public access to VPN resource using NGINX reverse proxy
I'll try my best to describe the scenario. I know that what I am willing to do might look unethical, but feel free to disregard my question.
This is the thing: I need to access a GitLab instance that is only accessible through a VPN using a public address. I do not maintain the VPN server, which is outdated and not properly configured. For example, I cannot connect to it with the latest version of Ubuntu because the newest OpenVPN version does not accept the old cipher that the server uses. Let's call this GitLab instance git.local.
I do have a server, on another site, with a public IP address and a domain name assigned to it. Let's call this server myserver.com. What I want to do is configure nginx as a reverse proxy, so that users accessing https://myserver.com (with SSL) have the requests forwarded to http://git.local (no SSL, I cannot change it). I was able to connect myserver.com to the VPN downgrading the OpenVPN client, something I don't want to do with the other clients.
The first thing I did was write a Docker Compose file for generating the SSL certificates and running nginx:
services:
  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot:latest
    volumes:
      - ./.docker/certbot/www/:/var/www/certbot/:rw
      - ./.docker/certbot/conf/:/etc/letsencrypt/:rw

  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: web
    restart: unless-stopped
    network_mode: "host"
    volumes:
      - ./.docker/nginx/conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/:ro
      - ./.docker/certbot/www/:/var/www/certbot/:ro
      - ./.docker/certbot/conf/:/etc/letsencrypt/:ro

The nginx configuration file is this:
client_max_body_size 200M;

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myserver.com ;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    # Challenge for CertBot/Let's Encrypt certificates.
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name myserver.com;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.php index.html;

    charset utf-8;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://10.8.30.191; // This is the IP of the GitLab in the VPN
        proxy_set_header Host git.local;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        sub_filter 'git.local' 'myserver.com';
        sub_filter_once off;
    }
}

At first, when I went https://myserver.com the GitLab login page appeared. But after a few clicks, some of the links revert to http://git.local. I thought that the sub_filter clause would change every string git.local to myserver.com. Does it go through the whole response or just the header? Is there any chance that the javascript code running in the browser is tied to git.local?
